# order date for values with unknown day and month

Tags: sql, dql

I'm developing a website with events from the past. For some events the whole date is known, for some the month of the year and for some only the year. Table event looks like:

```
id
content
date -> YYYY-MM-DD (date data type)
year -> true, if only year is known, otherwise false
monthandyear -> true if only year and month is known, otherwise false
```

I would like to list the contents of the table in the following order:

- descending by date
- if only the month and year are known (monthandyear is set to
  true), the content should be listed as the last of that month
- if only the year is known (year is set to true), the content should be listed as the last of that year

What is the best solution to this problem?

I'm using DQL:

```
SELECT p FROM App:Event p ORDER BY p.date DESC ...
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  What is the data type of `date`?

Comment: date is date type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional logic.  Assuming that `date` is a string:

```
order by left(date, 4),
         (case when not year and not yearmonth then 1 else 2 end),
         left(date, 7),
         (case when not yearmonth then 1  else 2 end)
         date
```

Edit:

If `date` is of type `date`, then:

```
order by year(date),
         (case when not year and not yearmonth then 1 else 2 end),
         month(date),
         (case when not yearmonth then 1  else 2 end)
         date
```

Comment: Thanks. I will translate this into DQL syntax. I can use SUBSTRING(), to work with dates.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using Gordon's answer. In DQL it looks like:

```
$this->getEntityManager()
     ->createQuery(
            'SELECT '
                . 'p, '
                . '(CASE WHEN (p.year = :yes) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) as HIDDEN ORD1, '
                . '(CASE WHEN (p.monthandyear = :yes) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) as HIDDEN ORD2 '
                . 'FROM App:Event p '
                . 'ORDER BY SUBSTRING(p.dateandtime, 1, 4) DESC, ORD1 DESC, SUBSTRING(p.dateandtime, 1, 7) DESC, ORD2 DESC, p.dateandtime DESC'  
        )
        ->setParameters(array("no" => false, "yes" => true))
        ->getResult();
```